# Should I use lock when using C# asynchronous/standby?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, locking

```
class A
{
    public int a = 0;

    public async Task Test1()
    {
        
        Console.WriteLine("Test1 START");

        for (long i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
        {
            a++;
            await Task.Yield();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Test1 END");
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        A a = new A();
        Task t1 = a.Test1();
        Console.WriteLine("1");
        Task t2 = a.Test1();
        Console.WriteLine("2");
        Task t3 = a.Test1();
        Console.WriteLine("3");
        Task t4 = a.Test1();
        Console.WriteLine("4");
        Task t5 = a.Test1();
        Console.WriteLine("5");

        while (!t1.IsCompleted || !t2.IsCompleted || !t3.IsCompleted || !t4.IsCompleted || !t5.IsCompleted)
        {

        }
        Console.WriteLine(a.a);

        Console.WriteLine("Main END");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

I made the code as above and the estimate is 50000. However, the result value can be less than or equal to 50000. What's the reason? It's an asynchronous process, but it works with a single thread, so I think I should get 50000.

---

```
public async Task Test1()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Start Thraed ID : " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

    for (long i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
    {
        a++;
        await Task.Yield();
    }

    Console.WriteLine("END Thraed ID : " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
}
```

result:

```
Start Thraed ID : 1
1
Start Thraed ID : 1
2
Start Thraed ID : 1
3
Start Thraed ID : 1
4
Start Thraed ID : 1
5
END Thraed ID : 14
END Thraed ID : 14
END Thraed ID : 5
END Thraed ID : 6
END Thraed ID : 6
50000
Main END
```

I modified the Test1 function like this and got this result. It seems to be running on a different thread. I misunderstood. Thank you.

Comment: For your specific example you should be incrementing `a` by calling `Interlocked.Increment(ref a);` otherwise you'll get weird results such as you describe.

Comment: _"but it works with a single thread"_ - how do you know?

Comment: The reason it doesn't work is as follows: Assume that `a` is 0. Thread 1 reads `a` as zero, then thread 2 reads `a` as zero (before either thread increments `a`). Then thread 1 adds 1 to zero and assigns the result (1) to `a`. Finally thread 2 adds 1 to zero and assigns the result (1) to `a`. So you've effectively skipped an increment because both increments started with the same value.

Comment: ^^ and if you had assumed this is only using one single thread, you would be surprised by that behavior. But that's because your assumption was wrong to begin with.

Comment: According to the document at https://learn.microsoft.com/ko-kr/dotnet/csharp/asynchronous-programming/async-scenarios, it is stated that when using Task.Run, it starts in a background thread. So I thought that if I simply call an async function without using Task.Run, the asynchronous function would be executed in the main thread.

Comment: @박재한 no, this does not mean that at all. Just because Task.Run() schedules tasks onto some thread, doesn't mean that other approaches don't.

Comment: @박재한 Try putting the following line at the start of `Test1()`: `Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);` - that will show you that different threads are running.

Comment: Better look at the value of _a_ when the loop of each test starts. It shows clearly the problem

Comment: _"So I thought that if I simply call an async function without using Task.Run, the asynchronous function would be executed in the main thread"_ - It is up until it encounters the first `await`. From there, "it depends".